# SQL relationship between student, lessons and attendance

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, erd

For a school project I'm trying to store students, their attendance and which online lessons they are allowed to view.

For example a yellow belt student is allowed to watch white and yellow belt lessons. The belt system is replaced by a kyu, which can also have a dan.

So far I've created the following:

- `Student`: studentID (PK), firstname, lastname, age, kyu, dan
- `Attendance`: attendanceID (PK), studentID (FK), date
- `Lesson`: lessonID(PK), name, kyu, dan

I'm stuck at finding a possible relationship between lesson and student, since it feels wrong to just put a FK to lesson in student.

As far as I'm aware, it's just one big class, so I can't form a relationship between student-class and class-lesson.

Comment: Maybe add another FK field to attendance? lessonId, for example. Edit: should have put this as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have a N-M relationship between lessons and students, where each student can enroll in several lessons, and each lesson may be (and hopefully is) taken by many students.

The typical way to represent such relationship is to create a bridge table, that stores which student participates which lesson. Say table `student_lesson` :

- `id` : primary key
- `lessonID` : foreign key towards table lesson
- `studentID` : foreign key towards table student

You would need to create a unique constraint on columns (lessonID, studentID) - or drop skip `id`, and make (lessonID, studentID) the primary key of the bridge table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, it should be many to many relationship, as many students can go to the same lesson, and student can have many leasons, so another table holding student and leason id will solve the problem, I think